# SQL Server Performance New Table vs New Columns

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We having complex DB having many tables with billions of data, we are going to redesign this DB to increase DB performance.

We are going to delete some of tables and merging this data with existing tables with add 6-7 new colums to existing related table. is this help us in performance increase ??

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer this. What are the 6-7 columns, and why do you think that adding them will help? what is the data being merged / removed? What are the current performance issues? What is the indexing strategies? What are the queries that are badly performing? Basically, what you ask is much more complex than a "is this help us in performance increase?" question

Comment: We having a SP in this we are calling about 20+ tables, when we execute query it's taking about 30 seconds. To overcome this issue in above 20+ tables we are going to cut down about 8-10 tables by adding extra columns in current tables. In one table we having about 10 columns by adding 3-4 more extra columns to related table we can delete an average 2-4 tables. By deleting this tables and adding extra columns to related table we will get more performance ??

Comment: That still depends on a **lot** of things. Indexing strategy mainly, but also the current query - i.e. is it a join, etc. Frankly your best bet is to try it on your test environment, and see how it behaves

Comment: If you have to ask a question like this here, then the answer is "*NO*", whatever you are trying to do will very *very* likely *NOT* have the result you want. If you have "*complex DB having many tables with billions of data*", then you ***need*** to get someone who knows what they are doing. This subject is at least as complex as your database and a three sentence question on a public forum is not going to result in the depth of direction and insight that you need.  Pay the money and get someone good.

Answer (score 1):

If its reduces the joins in the Query then its always better. If you are handling large amount of data then Denormalizing is one of the option to improve the performance. You can go through the link below for better understanding. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The new column is better than the new table with a one-to-one relationship because the size of the database in the new column is much smaller than creating a relationship between two tables and occupying system resources.

Answer (score 0):

you can use index for increase performance.

If you use these tables for reporting it is wise to use index keys.

Comment: Welcome to SE, amir. This community generally welcomes your help and competence. However, please note that professional offers are generally frowned upon. The help you provide here you provide for free and out of generosity. (While linking your SO-Profile with your company and vice versa is fine)